# How to increment cell values for rows, but to repeat them in columns?

Tags: excel, vba, increment

I have a piece of code which works good, but I would like to increment these values by column. Let's say I have 60 cells in columns A-E, so I have `ID_1` to `ID_60` in col A, B...E. My code works the way `B1` is `ID_61`

Any suggestion how to fix it?

EDIT: code with changed variable names:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
Dim HeaderName As String

HeaderName = Join(Array("Country", "City", "X", "Y"))
      
Dim LastUsedCell As Range

        Set LastUsedCell = Nothing
        Set LastUsedCell = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        
        If Not LastUsedCell Is Nothing Then
        
            Dim HeaderRow As Range
            Set HeaderRow = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, ws.Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                     
            Indeks = 0
            
            For Each Header In HeaderRow
                If InStr(1, HeaderName, Header.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
                
        Dim RangeToAnonimize As Range
        Set RangeToAnonimize = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, Header.Column), ws.Cells(LastUsedCell.Row, Header.Column))
   
                    For Each cell In RangeToAnonimize
                        cell.Value2 = "ID_" & Indeks
                        Indeks = Indeks + 1
                    Next cell
                End If
            Next Header
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

What the code does:

[image]

However, the intention is that one row should have the same ID.

Comment: Thank you, now it is much more clear. One more question: what is your desired output?

Comment: As I mentioned I got 57 rows per column. I would like to anonimize my data, so the 1st row got ID_1 and so on to ID_57, except the variables from array which is covered by InStr = 0 function. My problem is that B1 cell  is ID_58, not ID_1 again. So the counter of Indeks does not reset when comes to next column and so on

Comment: just so I'm clear, you want A2:E2 to be "ID_0" and A3:E3 to be "ID_1", etc.  Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Indeks = 0` should be just before `For Each cell`

```
Indeks = 0
For Each cell In RangeToAnonimize
```